# flutter: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1 flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im pretty new to flutter only a few months and still learning.

Im making a survey app that uses firebase when submitting the answer i get this range error.

> flutter: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1
> flutter: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 2

The Answer come from a list of textEditingControllers which goes through a 4 loop and stores the info in firebase and separate docs.

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import '../consts/colors.dart';
import '../widgets/advert_banner.dart';
import '../widgets/side_menu.dart';
import '../widgets/text_widget.dart';

class ViewSurveyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String DocName;
  ViewSurveyPage({required this.DocName});

  @override
  State<ViewSurveyPage> createState() => _ViewSurveyPageState(docName: DocName);
}

class _ViewSurveyPageState extends State<ViewSurveyPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String docName;
  _ViewSurveyPageState({required this.docName});
  List<String> _questionList = [];
  int pageIndex = 2;
  late CollectionReference surveryQuestions =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('surveys/$docName/questions');

  List<String> docIDs = [];
  List<TextEditingController> _answerList = [];

  Future getDocID() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('surveys/$docName/questions')
        .get()
        .then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
            docIDs.add(document.reference.id);
            _answerList.add(TextEditingController());
          }),
        );
  }

  pageSelector({required double screenHeight, required double screenWidth}) {
    if (pageIndex == 1) {
      return Container(
        width: screenWidth,
        height: screenHeight * 0.65,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: screenHeight * 0.15,
            height: screenHeight * 0.15,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: EESBlue,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    if (pageIndex == 2) {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
        width: screenWidth,
        height: screenHeight * 0.65,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getDocID(),
          builder: (context, index) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: docIDs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                      future: surveryQuestions.doc(docIDs[index]).get(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                          Map<String, dynamic> data =
                              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                          _questionList.add(data['question']);

                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              width: screenWidth,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color:
                                          Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.25),
                                      offset: Offset(0, 4),
                                      blurRadius: 50),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 10),
                                    child: TextWidget(
                                      text: '${data['question']}',
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      isHeading: true,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: screenWidth * 0.55,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: buttonColor,
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      horizontal: 15.0),
                                              child: TextField(
                                                controller: _answerList[index],
                                                style:
                                                    textFliedHintStyle.copyWith(
                                                        color: Colors.white),
                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                    hintText: 'ANSWER',
                                                    hintStyle:
                                                        textFliedHintStyle
                                                            .copyWith(
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .white)),
                                                maxLines: null,
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            width: screenWidth,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.grey[300],
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.25),
                                    offset: Offset(0, 4),
                                    blurRadius: 50),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 10),
                                  child: TextWidget(
                                    text: 'LOADING',
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    isHeading: true,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: screenWidth * 0.55,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: buttonColor,
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                horizontal: 15.0),
                                            child: TextField(
                                              style:
                                                  textFliedHintStyle.copyWith(
                                                      color: Colors.white),
                                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  hintText: 'LOADING',
                                                  hintStyle: textFliedHintStyle
                                                      .copyWith(
                                                          color: Colors.white)),
                                              maxLines: null,
                                            )),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                });
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  AnswerSurvey() async {
    setState(() {
      pageIndex = 1;
    });
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid != null && _answerList != null) {
      print(docIDs);
      print(_questionList);
      print(_answerList);

      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('surveys/$docName/answers')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .set({
        'user email': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
      });

      for (var i = 0; i < docIDs.length; i++) {
        try {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection(
                  'surveys/$docName/answers/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}/answers')
              .doc('option ${i.toString()}')
              .set({
            'question': _questionList[i],
            'answer': _answerList[i].text,
          });
          showSnackBar('SURVEY HAS BEEN SUBMITTED', context);
          Navigator.pop(context);
          _answerList[i].dispose();
          _answerList.clear();
        } catch (e) {
          showSnackBar('$e', context);
          print(e);
        }
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      pageIndex = 2;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _answerList.clear();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),
      backgroundColor: EESBlue,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          //APP BAR
          Container(
            height: screenHeight * 0.25,
            width: screenWidth,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: EESBlue,
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: screenHeight * 0.035,
                          width: screenHeight * 0.035,
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            'images/icons/back.svg',
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextWidget(
                      text: 'EES MOBILE APP',
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: screenHeight * 0.035,
                          width: screenHeight * 0.035,
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            'images/icons/menu.svg',
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: screenWidth,
                    height: screenHeight * 0.1,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: TextWidget(
                        text: '$docName',
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 71, 113),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          //BODY PAGE
          pageSelector(screenHeight: screenHeight, screenWidth: screenWidth),
          Container(
              height: screenHeight * 0.1,
              width: screenWidth,
              color: EESBlue,
              child: Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    AnswerSurvey();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: screenWidth * 0.5,
                    height: screenHeight * 0.06,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                        child: TextWidget(
                      text: 'SUMBIT',
                      color: bluetext,
                      isHeading: true,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: One possibility is that the length of _answerList is not the same as the number of questions in the survey. This could cause an issue when you loop through the list of controllers to retrieve the answers.

Comment: the problem is most likely related to the way you are initializing the _answerList and docIDs lists. The getDocID() method seems to be trying to add elements to these lists based on the query results from the Firebase database. However, the FutureBuilder inside the ListView.builder is likely causing the list initialization to occur multiple times, leading to the same elements being added to the list multiple times.

Comment: @Cameron - Please edit the question to provide more information,  Comments, and answers are not suitable places for that.

Comment: @RohitGupta Will do, sorry its my first time asking a question still trying to see how it all works

Answer (score 0):

You are using `index` which is based on `docIDs.length` in your `_answerList[index]`. Your `_answerList` doesn't have to be same length as `docIDs`. This causes your problem.
I recommend filling your `_answerList` in your `ListView.builder` like this

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: docIDs.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    _answerList.add(TextEditingController());
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: surveryQuestions.doc(docIDs[index]).get(),
    ...
```

and on dispose you should make sure you cleared everything

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var answerController in _answerList) {
      answerController.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

the FutureBuilder inside the ListView.builder is likely causing the list initialization to occur multiple times

you can move the initialization of these lists to the initState() method of your _ViewSurveyPageState class, and use a separate Future to fetch the data from Firebase. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
 class _ViewSurveyPageState extends State<ViewSurveyPage> {
          // ...
        
          List<String> _questionList = [];
          late CollectionReference surveryQuestions;
        
          List<String> docIDs = [];
          List<TextEditingController> _answerList = [];
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            surveryQuestions = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('surveys/$docName/questions');
            _fetchDataFromFirebase();
          }
        
          Future<void> _fetchDataFromFirebase() async {
            final querySnapshot = await surveryQuestions.get();
            docIDs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.id).toList();
            _answerList = List.generate(docIDs.length, (_) => TextEditingController());
          }
        
          // ...
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Dewa, Do i need to make any changes to my future builders and list builder as know i get 2 sets of the same data my apologies im still learning.

Comment: yes, you need to handle the error, loading the view, and finally display the data manually without Future Builder API.

Comment: Hey Dewa i have made the changes however i still receive the same error now im using a list builder and displaying it with the list and index.